# exception accessing MSSQL filetable data within EF core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

The same code works with a SQL-Server DB in-house but not with a SQL Server DB hosted on an Azure VM. Both are SQL Server 2019.

This is most certainly not a programming question. But I don't know here else to post this question. Anyway, does anyone have a clue, what the problem might be? Or can anyone point me to a source to find the answer?

I already tried to:

- update the NuGet packages
- update the Azure VM
- rebuild the model class from EF scaffolding
- query Google

all without success. So, any help would be highly appreciated

The Exception thrown:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=No pattern found for: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010010000110011001000111110000000
  Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchy.KnownPatterns.GetPatternByPrefix(BitReader bitR)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Read(BinaryReader r)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.HierarchyId.Read(BinaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.SqlServerHierarchyIdValueConverter.fromProvider(SqlBytes bytes)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ZOOM.DMS.Services.FileTableService.<GetDocument>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\ZOOM DMS\ZOOM.DMS\Services\FileTableService.cs:line 98

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ZOOM.DMS.Services.FileTableService.GetDocument(System.Guid) in FileTableService.cs
```

The query where the exception gets thrown:

```
                Document document = await _ctx.Documents
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(d => d.StreamId == streamId);
```

The Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ZOOM.DMS.Entities
{
    public class Document
    {
        public Document()
        {
            InverseParentPathNavigation = new HashSet<Document>();
        }

        [Column("stream_id")]
        public Guid StreamId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [Column("file_stream")]
        public byte[] FileStream { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("name")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("path_locator")]
        public HierarchyId Path { get; set; }

        [Column("parent_path_locator")]
        public HierarchyId ParentPath { get; set; }

        [Column("file_type")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FileType { get; set; }

        [Column("cached_file_size")]
        public long? CachedFileSize { get; set; }

        [Column("creation_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreationTime { get; set; }

        [Column("last_write_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset LastWriteTime { get; set; }

        [Column("last_access_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset? LastAccessTime { get; set; }

        [Column("is_directory")]
        public bool IsDirectory { get; set; }

        [Column("is_offline")]
        public bool IsOffline { get; set; }

        [Column("is_hidden")]
         public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        [Column("is_readonly")]
        public bool IsReadonly { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("is_archive")]
        public bool? IsArchive { get; set; }

        [Column("is_system")]
        public bool IsSystem { get; set; }

        [Column("is_temporary")]
        public bool IsTemporary { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentPath))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Document.InverseParentPathNavigation))]
        public virtual Document ParentPathNavigation { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Document.ParentPathNavigation))]
        public virtual ICollection<Document> InverseParentPathNavigation { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DocumentData> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems related to issues [#35](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/issues/35), [#49](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/issues/49), [#55](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/pull/55) and [#56](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/pull/56). Possibly you have a newer release of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` locally than is installed on AZ.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand right. The Program code I execute is always the same, only the database connection is changing. Meanwhile I tried with three DB servers. AZ and my local machine don't work, our in-house DB server does work. So, I would think that Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is always the same isn't it?

Comment: If you're running the exact same executable and just changing the connection string in the .config file to point to different servers then, yes, I would expect the same outcome for all servers. Maybe it's a different issue.

Comment: This is absolutely the case. So, it must be a different issue. What about collations?